# How do I write multiple strings into a file without them overwriting each other on rust 1.26 and onwards?

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble writing a few strings into my .txt file without them overwriting each other

This is an example:

```
for i in 1..100{

        fs::write("*PATH*", i.to_string()).expect("Unable to write file");
}
```

I'm thinking it should write every singe one right after each other but it doesn't! It overwrites and when I open the document it's just the last written number.

I couldn't find anything on the web since this way of writing into files seems to be rather new.

Comment: Append all strings before writing to file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) before entering the loop. You can further simplify writing to the file, by using the [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) and [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) macros. Which allows you to utilize Rust's [formatting functionality](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) avoiding the need to explicitly do `i.to_string()`.

Since you're performing a lot of (small) writes, then consider also wrapping it in a [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) to minimize the amount of total system calls performed.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

fn main() {
    let path = "...";
    let f = File::create(path).expect("unable to create file");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(f);

    for i in 1..100 {
        write!(f, "{}", i).expect("unable to write");
    }
}
```

If the file already exists, and you want to continuously append to it every time you execute your program. Then you can open it using [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) and specifically enabling append mode by using [`append(true)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append):

```rust
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

fn main() {
    let path = "...";
    let f = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open(path)
        .expect("unable to open file");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(f);

    for i in 1..100 {
        write!(f, "{}", i).expect("unable to write");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've removed the final `BufWriter` example and added it to the 2 other examples :)

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find anything on the web since this way of writing into files seems to be rather new.

It's not rather new, it's rather wrong (for this use case). Open the file beforehand and write to that so it appends, instead of calling [`fs::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.write.html) every single loop, which will reopen and close the file every iteration, which is not only slow, but causes your file to get overwritten:

```rust
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::prelude::*;

let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .open("/path/to/file")
    .expect("Could not open file");

for i in 1..100 {
    file.write_all(i.to_string().as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write to file");
}
```